# Jquerymobile Select Menu not working for more than 73 records

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-mobile, menu

I have a select menu being populated by an Ajax call to a php script that returns the list of products from a table in XML form.

The product table has about 400 records and for some reason, the select menu displays nothing with a select statement that returns all. Troubleshooting with Firebug, I can see the php code is successfully returning ALL 400 records correctly to the browser but it does not get displayed.

When I alter the select statement to be "SELECT ProductID,ProductName FROM product WHERE ProductID < 74", it works, displaying the first 73 items. Thinking this could possibly be due to something wrong with item 74, I altered the where clause to "> 74" but this also returned nothing. A where clause of " > 74 and < 120" however works.

What could possibly be the cause? Please find the code snippets below.

The javascript of the code is as follows:

```
function populateProducts(xmlindata) {

var mySelect = $('#ili_product');
 $(xmlindata).find("Product").each(function()
  {
    optionValue=$(this).find("id").text();
    optionText = $(this).find("name").text();
    mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(optionValue).html(optionText));    
  });
}
```

The php code is:

```
<?php

include("dbconfig.inc.php");

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
echo "<products>\n";
$select = "SELECT ProductID,ProductName FROM product";
try {
    foreach($dbh->query($select) as $row) {
        echo "<Product>\n\t<id>".$row['ProductID']."</id>\n\t<name>".$row['ProductName']."</name>\n</Product>\n";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

echo "</products>";
?>
```

Comment: Just a wild guess : maybe some max size for the xml string on the javascript size ? Check if `xmlindata` is complete or truncated. If `xmlindata`, check if `$(xmlindata)` returns a correct object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good practice to escape quotes and other characters while generating/forming html based on xml/json data

In your case,

`optionValue=$(this).find("id").text().replace('\'','&quot;');`

or `replace("'", "&rsquo;");`

This way you escape quotes, if they are the ones causing the problem. Not sure if the problem is due to breaking of the strings.

you can escape multiple characters like this.

`.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/'/g, "&quot;")`;

Notice `//` Regex and the `g` flag, this will find the characters globally.

Comment: Actually the select menu also works with " > 73 AND < 120". Thanks but this didn't work.

Comment: may be problem is with ur xml data, how are you getting xml data? Put some snippet in the question for this.

Comment: You know what? You were absolutely spot-on: it's due to a character giving the XML generation code some challenges. Ampersand in this case. I see this from Firebug: XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: moz-nullprincipal:{597b355e-9735-4822-a05b-a57f58191e0f} Line Number 545, Column 14:

 <name>JOHNSON & JOHNSON </name>
--------------------^.

Being a newbie I'd ask: is there a general way to expunge/escape all potentially problematic characters as opposed to specific ones like your code snippet above?

Thank you so much!

Comment: list of characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references. there are only few. you can escape them all.

Answer (score 0):

It might be also because of some illegal characters in your returned data which were not escaped properly..

Check if  console.log($(xmlindata)) returns all the data .. Especially check for values that might have characters like **"** or **'** inside the values that might break your string

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: xmlindata is not defined" in firebug for this. However the "post" tab shows the complete list of items correctly returned.